# trouble with a method that needs to interact with another method in certain way

Tags: java, methods

i'm relatively new to programming and i'm practicing some code. I got stumped trying to do this one goal. I'm trying to make a class in java that takes numbers and multiplies them depending on certain parameters. the theme is "how a bike works" with variables such as "speed" and "gear" and methods such as "gearshift" and "accelerate". the purpose of the gearshift method is to multiply the speed by whatever the input of the gear is. My problem here is i need a way to make the variable gear work, as I cant just assign gear to my input or else the way I have it set up the speed will be zero. I need to find a way in which you can have a default setting for gear and not have integers stack on top of the default at the same time so that way if someone types in to the speed method in the tester without setting a gear the output wont be something other than what the default speed is. I tried making gear equal to count (the input) but that would just make gear equal to 0 if there were no inputs. I need the gear to be equal to 1 if there are no inputs I also tried doing gear= count+1 but that would just make numbers higher than 0 stack on top of each other for example 1 would be 2 and 2 would be 3.

```
public class bike
{
    public bike()
    {
        speed = 0;
        gear = 0;
    }
    public void accelerate(int count)
    {
        speed = count* gear;    
    }
    public void gearshift(int count)
    {
        gear = count;   
    }
    public double total ()
    {
        return speed;   
    }
    private int speed;
    private int gear;
}
```

An example of an expected result would be if I were to input 5 into accelerate in a tester class and then put 2 into gearshift then printed the total then I would get a final speed of 10.
Another expected result would be if I were to not put anything into the gearshift method at all and I were to put 5 into speed then if I printed the total i would get the speed.`enter code here`

Answer (score 2):

First, I formatted your code to make it look a little more convenient.
I set the default gear to 1, because a bike doesn´t have a 0'th gear I guess.

```
public class Bike{
    private int speed;
    private int gear;

    public Bike(){
        speed = 0;
        gear = 1;
    }
    public void accelerate(int count){
        speed = count * gear;    
    }
    public void gearshift(int count){
       gear = count;   
    }
    public double total (){
        return speed;   
    }
}
```

With this, you should be good to go as a first try in learning this.

You can later try to do a more sophisticated accelerating, like adding the acceleration to the current speed, like a real bike doesnt stop at once or accelerate from 0 to 20 mph/kmh in actually NO time.
furthermore, you could add an if-condition inside your gearshift-function, to make sure the bike is not set to gear -10 or 24532.